# How to "invoke" a class instance in PHP?

Tags: php, class, instance, invoke

is there any possibility to "invoke" a class instance by a string representation?

In this case i would expect code to look like this:

```
class MyClass {
  public $attribute;
}

$obj = getInstanceOf( "MyClass"); //$obj is now an instance of MyClass
$obj->attribute = "Hello World";
```

I think this must be possible, as PHP's SoapClient accepts a list of classMappings which is used to map a WSDL element to a PHP Class. But how is the SoapClient "invoking" the class instances?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$class = 'MyClass';
$instance = new $class;
```

However, if your class' constructor accepts a variable number of arguments, and you hold those arguments in an array (sort of `call_user_func_array`), you have to use reflection:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$args  = array('foo', 'bar');
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

There is also `ReflectionClass::newInstance`, but it does the same thing as the first option above.

Reference:

- [Object instantiation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)
- [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)
- [ReflectionClass::newInstance()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php)

Comment: Ah tanks, that easy. :-D

One more question, is there a way to test if that class really exist?

Like:

if( classExists( "MyClass")) {
  $obj = getInstanceOf( "MyClass");
}

Comment: There's `class_exists()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php. Watch for the second argument though.

Comment: Thank you guys. ReflectionClass is the perfect solution. Well i forgot that this is called Reflection not invoking. :-)

Comment: newInstanceArgs function made my day. The last piece to finish my dependency resolver, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 14):

The other answers will work in PHP <= 5.5, but this task gets a lot easier in PHP 5.6 where you don't even have to use reflection. Just do:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct($var1, $var2)
    {}
}

$class = "MyClass";
$args = ['someValue', 'someOtherValue'];

// Here's the magic
$instance = new $class(...$args);
```

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. Had no idea the "splat" operator even existed until today! http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Answer (score 6):

If the number of arguments needed by the constructor is known and constant, you can (as others have suggested) do this:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$obj = new $className($arg1, $arg2, etc.); 
$obj->attribute = "Hello World";
```

As an alternative you could use Reflection. This also means you can provide an array of constructor arguments if you don't know how many you will need.

```
<?php
$rf = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$obj = $rf->newInstanceArgs($arrayOfArguments);
$obj->attribute = "Hello World";
```