# Dynamically instantiate class from another

Tags: php

I made an example to better explain the situation. If I run this

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        return new B(func_get_args());
    }
}

class B
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }
}

$obj = new A('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I get

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  }
}
```

But what if the constructor prototype of B is `public function __construct($var1, $va2, $var3)`? How could I pass the parameters to it if I don't know the exact numbers of parameters of the B constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "invoke" a class instance in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542717/how-to-invoke-a-class-instance-in-php)

Comment: You've edited this question to rename class `A` to `Instantiator`. If you now try to create an instance of `A` it won't be found.

Comment: you should check out ReflectionClass::getConstructor and ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs. This will enable you to find out the number of args and instantiate the object

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the one which you are looking for, But with the best of my knowledge I think there is no other solution.

```
Class A {
        public function __construct()
        {
            return new B(func_get_args());
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        public function __construct($paramArr = array())
        {
            var_dump($paramArr);
        }
    }

    $obj = new A('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: I updated my question: I meant what if I don't know how many parameters does the B constructor have?

Comment: I don't think this will work - constructors cannot be asked to explicitly return something, since they are designed to return an instance of the class requested.